# Non-Parametric Regression with Ordinal Independent Variables

Tags: r, regression, nonparametric, ordinal-data

I'm trying to find a model to predict a test score (0 to 100) from many independent ordinal variables (all are on a 1 to 10 scale).  Since there are SO many ordinal variables, using binary dummy variables would probably be a mess.  The test scores are skewed, (as well as many of the ordinal variables) so I'd like to use a non-parametric approach.

Another issue/thing to keep in mind is that a score of 10 on the predictor variables does not necessarily predict a higher test score.  For example: a score of 2 in one predictor may predict a high test score, while a score of 8 on another may predict a high test score.  Not sure what model to use and how to deal with all of the ordinal variables.  I'm working in R, so please put any coding advice in R.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no other common way to deal with ordinal regressors - if you reject to treat them as interval - as via optimal scaling (= optimal quantification) which transforms the regressors into interval nonlinearly so as to maximize the prediction of the dependent. In SPSS, for instance, this known as categorical regression (CATREG). Search for it.

Comment: How many is "SO many"? The binary model matrix will likely be fairly sparse, and most R functions will produce this matrix for you. Unless you have millions of predictors and millions of samples, I'm not sure this is something to worry about.